# Rails Postgres HSTORE: PG::InternalError: ERROR: Syntax error near '=' at position 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to execute a where() with false, but instead is executing it as if I passed a query:

```
PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near '=' at position 1
LINE 1: ..."subject_users"."subject_id" = $1 AND (languages @> ' => 1')
                                                           ^
: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" INNER JOIN 
"subject_users" ON "users"."id" = "subject_users"."user_id" WHERE 
"subject_users"."subject_id" = $1 AND (languages @> '
```

First, I check whether the param is defined:

```
langs = defined?(params[:languages]).nil? ? false : "languages @> '#
{params[:languages]} => 1'"
```

Then I filter out users based on the subject and language, if none is chosen it evaluates to false and returns all users on that subject.

```
@subject_users = Subject.includes(:users)
    .where(name: params[:subject_type]).first.users
    .where(langs)
```

Comment: What do you expect `defined?(params[:languages]).nil?` to do? Have you tried `defined?(nil).nil?` to see what that gives you? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks a lot, changed it and worked.